# Identify the editor for githhub code

Tags: eclipse, git, nvd3.js

I have downloaded a zip file for nvd3js code and wanted to view the code in an editor/ IDE. When I unzip the package, bower was used to package the entire code. Im not sure/ how to identify which editor/IDE to use to import the code and view the entire project.

I tried to use the import option in eclipse to download and view the project/code in eclipse.But I was unable to do the same. In general, I would like to know, based on the project downloaded from GIT, how can we know, what IDE to use to view/edit the file.   Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: IDE is just a fancy text editor. You can also use notepad to view/edit files.

Comment: There is no "in general" solution, and there's barely even a problem. Source code is a bunch of text. Open it in whatever text editor you want. If it is tightly linked to a particular IDE, and unless there is some clear standard (e.g. Android Studio for Android projects or XCode for iOS), this should be indicated in the project's README.